# UINavigationController animation from view controller with prompt

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, visual-glitch

I am implementing an application that uses a UINavigationController. It currently shows 3 views, each a `UITableViewController`. The first view that is shown only has a `title`, while the other two have a `title` and `prompt`. All segues are created in the storyboard, which is rather straightforward: [image: Storyboard of UINavigationController]
The problem: As soon as I animate AWAY from a view that has a prompt, the animation glitches - the title (and sometimes the back button) "fly in" from the bottom, instead of from the right.

**Example:** https://youtu.be/N-K8piEJ1aY (recording with slow animations turned on)
Here you can see that the animation from first to second view works fine, but from second to third view is glitchy. animating back works.

This issue seems similar to [Weird animations when changing NavigationItem prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508975/weird-animations-when-changing-navigationitem-prompt) . The conclusion in that thread was that this only occurs on iOS 7, I am running on iOS 10.0/10.1, though. The issue occurs both in simulator and on the real device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fwiw I have run into the same issue. If I come up with any work arounds then I'll let you know

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was an absolute hack inspired by an absolute hack inspired by Catalina T. over on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053198/uinavigationbar-overlaps-uitableview-when-programatically-setting-prompt):

Either in `viewWillAppear:` on the appearing VC or after calling `pushViewController:animated:` on the navigation controller (or I'm guessing after calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` add the following code:

#### ObjC

```
// This is a hack that's because UINavigationBar with prompts is broken
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

#### Swift

```
// This is a hack that's because UINavigationBar with prompts is broken
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

where `navigationController` is a reference to the `UINavigationController` that's doing all the pushing (e.g. `viewController.navigationController`)

EDIT: It appears now there're other weird animations that occur when popping and repushing a VC, so this answer isn't a true solution. Leaving it up so as to help someone else down a similar rabbit hole.